# Excel 2007: plot data points not on an axis/ force linear x-incrementation without altering integrity of non-linear data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

In Excel, how does one go about plotting points that don't have an x component that is an x-axis label?

For example, in my graph, the x-components are derived from the cosine function and aren't linear, but Excel is displaying them as if .0016 to .0062 to .0135 is an equal incrementation.

How would I change this so that the x-axis has an even incrementation without altering the integrity of the points themselves? In other words, how do I plot a point with an x component independent from the x-axis label?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the "Scatter" Diagram type.